# How can I add the value of a Typescript enum to my javascript function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, enums, typescript

I created this appRun.ts file:

```
/// <reference path="app.ts"/>
/// <reference path="services/EnumsService.ts"/>
app.run(['$rootScope', appRun]);  
function appRun($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.Action = Action;
    $rootScope.AuthTabs = AuthTabs;
    $rootScope.UserTestStatus = UserTestStatus;
    $rootScope.Network = Network;
    $rootScope.TS = TS;
}
```

and in EnumsService.ts:

```
enum Action {
    None,
    Registering,
    Authenticating
}
```

But when it comes to my Javascript AppRun.js being created it does not know anything about the Action enum.

```
/// <reference path="app.ts"/>
/// <reference path="services/EnumsService.ts"/>
app.run(['$rootScope', appRun]);
function appRun($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.Action = Action;
    $rootScope.AuthTabs = AuthTabs;
    $rootScope.UserTestStatus = UserTestStatus;
    $rootScope.Network = Network;
    $rootScope.TS = TS;
}
//# sourceMappingURL=appRun.js.map
```

Comment: How do you compile the `appRun.ts` into `appRun.js`? How does the `tsc` command line look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using internal modules, you need to either...

1. Ensure all the scripts are loaded in order at runtime (usually by adding all the script tags to the page in the appropriate order)

or

2. Compile to a single file, so all of the scripts are included. If you have your reference comments set up correctly, the single file will be ordered

Example of compiling to a single file

```
tsc --out combined.js appRun.ts
```

You can also select this option in project settings if you are using Visual Studio.